# error is occured by url setting for action property

Tags: django, templates, url, action

maybe It looks like a Django template syntax error occurred.

I set url as action property 
in the form tag as below

```
    <form method="post" id="comment_form" action={% url "blog:comment_new" %}>
        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ comment_form }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
```

error status:
error is occured by this code:
action = {% url "blog: comment_new"%}

An error occurs when requesting url: 
url:http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1/

error message:
An error occurred NoReverseMatch at / blog / 1 /

[image]

I do n
ot know why.
Thank you if you can tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the pk as a keyword argument.

```
(?P<pk>\d+)
```

You should use this format when you are passing pk as a keyword argument.

```
{% url "blog:comment_new" object.pk %}
```

And in this part piece of code, you need to place the pk of the object.

Comment: I forgot I needed post.pk like a fool. The problem is solved and the answer is well saved. Thank you for your kind reply.